# converting ppt/pptx to pdf using C

Tags: c, unix, pdf, powerpoint

I am not talking about exact conversion. If I could get just the text out of it, I am happy.

Any pointers? Anything I can look at?

Comment: Do you mean like without using any libraries?  Only the C language?

Comment: @satuon libraries are fine, rather I want libraries if available :-)

Comment: do you really need to do it in C? Aren't there several available programs that can do this? Note the low # of followers for pdf and ppt tags. Might do well to search for some alternates. Consider searching here for XML tagged questions BUT THEN looking at the other tags attached, maybe there is a big group call text-conversion or something. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/) . Its python based(and openoffice needs to be installed), just a pointer that might help.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. But openoffice is a _HUGE_ beast. I would try to stay away from it.

Comment: Why do you want to do it? Is it just for your own use or you want to sell it?

Comment: Naah, no selling. I *hate* ppt/pptx thingi. It hurts my eyes. If possible I would seize them from existence. So, this is just for myself.

Comment: Still couldn't find anything for this. Will keep an eye open. :-)